# Book where kids get powers and the girl goes crazy and gets electrocuted

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, powers

I got this book from my middle school library in like 7-8th grade, so it’s probably for younger kids.

The plotline was that a group of kids gain powers (I don’t remember how); I think the powers have something to do with being indestructible. The girl begins to go crazy towards the end and the group has to electrocute her. I believe she survives.
I believe the girl is a new girl at their school.
I could be wrong but I kind of remember the kids switching off having powers.
Maybe they can’t die while they have the power?

Comment: Can you recall the approximate year that you read this?

Answer (score 1):

Is it ***[Thirteen Days to Midnight](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7155027)*** (2010) by Patrick Carman?

> You are indestructible . Three whispered words transfer an astonishing power to Jacob Fielding that changes everything. At first, Jacob is hesitant to use the power, unsure of its implications. But there's something addictive about testing the limits of fear.
>
> Then Ophelia James, the beautiful and daring new girl in town, suggests that they use the power to do good, to save others. But with every heroic act, the power grows into the specter of a curse. How to decide who lives and who dies?
>
> In this nail-biting novel of mystery and dark intrigue, Jacob must walk the razor thin line between right and wrong, good and evil, and life and death. And time is running out. Because the Grim Reaper doesn't disappear. . . . He catches up.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct book, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't.